# p:dataTable CSS row change onclick

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have one question concerning `<p:dataTable>` row CSS.
I have implemented a dataTable. In the css-File i have specified row-height as:

```css
.ui-datatable tbody td {
    height: 30px;
}
```

If you click on one row, the data and columns changes. Now I want to change the height of the rows (after the click on the row) too. Is there a possibility to change the row-height of the datatTable in the backing bean method `public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event){...}` or in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use css this works for me:

```
tr[role=row].ui-state-highlight td{
    height: 10px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: What does the role=row statement do?